# Finding Given Coordinate Positions in NumPy Array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

```
import numpy as np

ref_cols = [11, 5, 12, 13, 15]
ref_rows = [1, 11, 2, 3, 5]
rows, cols = np.mgrid[1:6, 11:16]
print cols

[[11 12 13 14 15]
 [11 12 13 14 15]
 [11 12 13 14 15]
 [11 12 13 14 15]
 [11 12 13 14 15]]
print rows

[[1 1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 3 3]
 [4 4 4 4 4]
 [5 5 5 5 5]]
```

I want to get where the given cols and rows (11,1), (5,11), (12,2), (13,3), (15,5) exists. So the expected answer is follows:

```
[[True, False, False, False, False],
[False, True, False, False, False],
[False, False, True, False, False],
[False, False, False, False, False],
[False, False, False, False, True]]
```

I tried as:

```
rows_indices = np.in1d(rows, ref_rows).reshape(rows.shape)
cols_indices = np.in1d(cols, ref_cols).reshape(cols.shape)
answers = (rows_indices & cols_indices)
print answers
```

But answer is wrong.

How to do it guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your try goes wrong is that you first need to evaluate each pair separately and you cannot evaluate first all rows and columns separately and then combine them in a logical operation.

Here is one way to fix it:

```
out = np.zeros(rows.shape, dtype=bool)
for r, c in zip(ref_rows, ref_cols):
    out |= (r == rows) & (c == cols)
print out
```

Comment: I could not understand the meaning of |=. Could you explain it?

Comment: Of course. The statement `a = a | b` (where `|` is the bitwise `or`-operator) can be shortened to `a |= b`.

Comment: Nice answer - might be a good idea to move the comment into the answer itself, because comments should be considered volatile...

Answer (score 2):

Probably there exists a more elegent solution but this works for me and is written in an vectorized way ...

```
import numpy as np

ref_cols = np.array([11, 5, 12, 13, 15])
ref_rows = np.array([1, 11, 2, 3, 5])
rows, cols = np.mgrid[1:6, 11:16]

m = (cols[:,:,None]==ref_cols[None,None,:]) & (rows[:,:,None]==ref_rows[None,None,:])

answer = np.any(m,axis=2)
#array([[ True, False, False, False, False],
#       [False,  True, False, False, False],
#       [False, False,  True, False, False],
#       [False, False, False, False, False],
#       [False, False, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: this may be true ... but it is vectorized and fast

Comment: I have never used vectorized way, could you explain for me?

Comment: sloppy saying ... it means avoiding `for` loops by using `numpy` functions which are 'usually' much faster than any loops. Your attempt above is for instance written in a vectorized way ... the other answer using the `for` loop is not. This does not mean that is a bad solution! Often, `for` loops are easier to understand in contrast to vectorized solutions which can look very complicated sometimes. However, when dealing with a lot of numbers vectorized codes are faster ... mostly